# EF - Performance issues with finding parent list from exact list of children

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I am using Entity Framework and am running into a performance issue that boils down to the following problem. I have two entities, `Condition` and `ConditionItem`, defined as follows:

```
public class Condition
{  
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual HashSet<ConditionItem> ConditionItems { get; set; }
}

public class ConditionItem : BaseEntity
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int ConditionId { get; set; } 
   public int OptionId { get; set; }
   // ... Other properties not shown for clarity
   [ForeignKey("ConditionId")]
   public virtual Condition Condition { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("OptionId")]
   public virtual Option Option { get; set; }
}
```

The definition of the entity `Option` is irrelevant to the problem.

Given a `Hashset<int>` of OptionId, that we will refer to as `hset` thereafter, I need to be able to:

- Return the value of the `Id` of the condition, whose associated list of ConditionItems' OptionId **exactly** matches the values from `hset`, if such condition exists.
- Otherwise, create a new `Condition` and its associated `ConditionItem`s, setting their `OptionId` property based on the values from `hset`, and returns the `Id` of the newly created `Condition`.

To do so, I first need to check if the Condition exists. For that, I am using the following Linq query:

```
Conditions.FirstOrDefault(x => hset.Count == x.ConditionItems.Count && x.ConditionItems.All(y => hset.Contains(y.OptionId))
```

If the above query returns a `Condition`, I can then easily access and return its `Id`. If it returns null, I know I have to create a new `Condition`.

While the above works as expected, it is proving to be tremendously slow when running with large datasets. For instance, we have currently around 50,000 Conditions and about half a million ConditionItems and it is taking more than 500 seconds to return the Id of 15,000 **existing** conditions. To clarify, this is only reading the database, no create/`SaveChanges` involved.

I expect that our datasets will continue to grow about 10 times.

Does anybody have any insight on how to significantly improve performance?

EDIT:

As indicated in the comment section, this process involves too many database requests and is causing the slowness referred to above.

I have looked at downloading the entire dataset first and then performing the Linq query. This is somewhat helping when trying to identify a large number of conditions (halving the time approximately, but still not good enough), but this has a very significantly negative impact on much smaller number of conditions.

I am looking to revert to stored procedures, but would like to ensure no other way exists before doing so.

In essence, I was hoping that, given an `IEnumerable<Hashset<int>>` representing a collection of "hset" as referred above, there could be a fast way to retrieve the list of `ConditionId` values, having in the sametime created those `Condition` entities that needed to be created.

Comment: Did you try to run the sql generated with an explain ? Tried directly with your own sql and see any performance difference ?

Comment: So you are executing 15K database **queries** in 500s, which is approx. 3ms per query. What do you expect?

Comment: @Ivan, yes I agree that each query is fast but the total number of queries makes the entire process slow. I have edited the question to clarify the expectation.